# Make git's patch.exe regard Windows line endings

Tags: windows, git, patch

Git for Windows has a patch.exe program that can apply patches to files. While that works well, it changes the line endings of all patched files from Windows CRLF to Unix LF. I needed to fix that in my text editor just now after applying a patch for several files.

There's also a patch.exe from UnxUtils, but that doesn't seem to work anymore today. It always wants administrative rights which I am not giving to it.

Is there some undocumented command line option to tell Git's patch to use and keep Windows line endings while we're on the Windows platform?

Comment: What type of patches are you dealing with? If they're good enough for `git am`, you could just use that instead (possibly with the `--keep-cr` option, depending on your Git settings). But that is a lot stricter about what's valid and what isn't, in my experience.

Comment: git am doesn't look like it would work outside of a git repository. That's where I need to apply the patch.

Comment: You're right, in that case, it wouldn't work. You never actually said that you were working with a Git repository, so my bad for not reading the question closely enough, but it may nonetheless be worthwhile editing the question to prevent others from making the same mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the UnxUtils patch.exe asks for admin privileges is due to its name. Microsoft chose to automatically assume programs called Setup or Patch or having these words in the description resource should require admin rights when running. To disable that you need a manifest that specifies the rights required. You can add a manifest file called 'patch.exe.manifest' in the same directory as your patch.exe file to define this. Or you can actually embed this as a manifest resource. Mine has the following as the manifest:

```
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" processorArchitecture="X86" name="patch.exe" type="win32"></assemblyIdentity>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false"></requestedExecutionLevel>
        </requestedPrivileges>
       </security>
  </trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

This doesn't really touch on why you are having issues with applying patches on windows. I use core.autocrlf = true on my system and don't suffer problems with cherry-pick or git am or apply that all use patch to apply changes. The version of patch shipped with Git for Windows has been through a number of tests and should work fine. Possibly you are using patch directly and maybe using 'git apply' to apply patch files might work better?

Comment: I have created a patch from one of my Git commits that I was doing on the master branch. That file has unknown line endings (says my editor, I guess they're just inconsistent). I've set autocrlf = false because I don't want Git to do anything to my files. I edit them with CRLF and they should be stored exactly like that. I have a very bad feeling about my files being invisibly converted to something else. Binary files or UNIX shell scripts may break. This patch file was applied to a non-Git directory of a different developer who doesn't use version control.

Comment: The manifest file has no effect. The Windows shield overlay icon disappears from patch.exe but running it still requests admin access. – Anyway, UnxUtil's patch.exe has the same --version output as Git's, so that probably won't help.